# How can one show algebraically that an angle is constructible?

Tags: field-theory, geometric-construction

For example an angle of 30 degrees.  I know that geometrically I can obtain the entire 30-60-90 triangle using the standard tools (compass, straightedge and unit length) and by performing iterations.  However, for this particular problem, I have to use field theoretic machinery.  I know that geometric construction problems have analogous problems in field theory involving extensions and irreducible polynomials, I'm just not exactly sure how the two are tied together.

Also, would something similar work for lengths like $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: In this connection please google also why an angle cannot be trisected.

Comment: A real number $x$ is constructible iff the degree of the normal closure of $\Bbb Q(x)$ over $\Bbb Q$ is a power of $2$ (in particular, the degree of $\Bbb Q(x)$ over $\Bbb Q$ is a power of $2$, but this is not sufficient). An angle $\theta$ can be constructed iff $x=\cos(\theta)$ can be constructed.

Comment: So basically I have to show that $\mathbb{Q}$($cos(30)$) = $\mathbb{Q}$($\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$) has degree 2 over  $\mathbb{Q}$?  Which I know it does, since the basis of this vector space would be {1, $\sqrt{3}$}.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. Here $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 3)$ is a normal extension of $\Bbb Q$, then since the degree is a power of $2$, $\sqrt 3$ is constructible and so is the angle $30°$.